Schtasks does not provide full access to the program
I wrote a small code in C, and want to try to run it through Schtasks. It started, but a winapi function, which requires administrator rights, did not work.
For cmd, I use this prompt (I launched it with administrator rights):
schtasks /create /ru SYSTEM /tn TestTask /tr "C:\Users\Koalko\Desktop\main.exe" /sc ONSTART
I also tried to add my profile to the Administrators group, but that didn't change anything:
net localgroup Administrators Koalko /add
My C code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        printf("\rBLOCK INPUT AFTER %d SECONDS", 5-i);
        Sleep(1000);
    }
    printf("\nBLOCK INPUT ON 5 SECONDS!!!\n");
    BlockInput(TRUE);
    Sleep(5000);
    BlockInput(FALSE);
    printf("RELEASE INPUT\n");
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

I don't think there is a problem in the code.

There is no API call here that requires administrator privileges.

@IInspectable BlockInput don't work without administrator rights

That's surprising. Forgive me for not putting too much thought into the requirements of an API that has no valid use case.

Regardless, I'm pretty sure that scheduled tasks run under a service context. Services run in Session 0. You cannot block input of an interactive session from a non-interactive session.

It also doesn't make sense to print output in a non-interactive session, either.

Ok, is there a way to run the program in interactive session with administrator privileges?

Thank a lot to IInspectable and Remy Lebeau.
The issue was that the program was running in a non-interactive session, therefore BlockInput could not be executed.
After reviewing the schtasks documentation, I found the /IT attribute which allows tasks to run in an interactive session.
It is important to note that this attribute does not work with the SYSTEM user and is not executed with /sc ONSTART.
schtasks /create /ru Koalko /tn TestTask /tr "C:\Users\Koalko\Desktop\main.exe" /sc ONLOGON /RL HIGHEST /IT /f

